# Let users create content by using the default (non-admin) theme

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, forms, webforms

sorry to ask a more conceptual question but I am really stuck.

I have a Drupal 7 site where users will sign in and then create a certain kind of content. I have the content set up ready to go.

Do I just let them have access to the `/node/add/[content-type]` page? If so, how can I theme this page so it has the headers / menus / footers of the rest of the website (and not the standard Drupal 'admin' view)?

I am able to add a custom `node-form.tpl.php` file but when I output the form using `echo drupal_render_children($form);` it still looks like the Drupal admin backend, and not a form that is consistent with the style of the rest of the website. I want it to look more like, say, a webform. Perhaps there a way to insert a `node/add` form into a panels page for example?

I feel like there is a "Drupal way" of doing it, it must be a fairly common use case but it seems my Google fu is failing me. Any help or advice appreciated.

**TLDR**; I want a node/add form to look like a standard website webform and not part of the Drupal admin/backend.

PS: I am using a custom theme and I am comfortable with custom modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might misunderstand you, or you did not yet try this. There is a permission `View the administration theme`, which normal users should not have.

This means that if you login as a less privileged user that has permission to `[Content type]: Create new content`, the add content page will look like any other front-end page already:

[image: Non-admin create page]

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful and answered my question - although in the end I did end up using the `form_block` module but this knowledge came in handy in another context. Seems obvious now!